# Uncaught syntax error - using PHP within Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm using the below code - earlier when I ran it, it worked fine and returned correct values.  I've since done something and now I'm getting *uncaught syntax error - unexpected identifier*.
I've put the code through JSLint and removed some of the PHP in case that was causing it but I have no idea what's gone wrong.
Any assistance is greatly appreciated

```
    $(function(){
    var cartTot = '<?=$previousorder->TotalOrderAmountExVAT;?>';
    var curr = '<?=$ShoppingCartSummary->Currency;?>';
    var ref = '<?=$previousorder->OurReferenceNumber;?>';
    var vatx = '<?=$previousorder->TotalVATAmount;?>';
    var prodid = '<?=$order->ProductCode;?>';
    var prodname = '<?=$order->ProductGroupName;?>';
    var rrp = '<?=$order->RRP;?>';
    var qnty = '<?=$order->Quantity;?>';
        dataLayer.push({
          'ecommerce': {
            'purchase': {
              'actionField': {
                'id': ref,                         
                'affiliation': 'Online Store',
                'revenue': cartTot,                
                'tax': vatx,
                'shipping': ''
              },
              'products': [{         
                'name': '<?php echo json_encode($name1); ?>', 
                'id': '<?php echo json_encode($id1); ?>',
                'price': '<?php echo json_encode($price1); ?>',
                'quantity': '<?php echo json_encode($quantity1); ?>'
              }]
            }
          }
        });
});
```

Comment: Please give us the resulting JS code

Comment: You should not use single-quotes around calls to `json_encode()`, as that will already provide you with a ready-to-use JavaScript expression. On a similar note, you should use `json_encode` for **everything**.

Comment: you should **never** mix PHP + JS - they're two different languages that get executed differently and should remain separate.

Comment: @Will what do you mean, sorry?  This prints an array to the datalayer

Comment: You need to look at the rendered JS in your browser to see exactly how the PHP is being parsed. You'll be able to see which line is giving bad data or not being printed properly.

Comment: @aynber thank you - this has solved it.  The string being passed from the PHP contained a single quote which was throwing an error